# Simple harmonic motion and trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, physics

Here's the question I would like help with:

> A particle is moving in simple harmonic motion according to $x=6\sin
>  \left (2t+\frac{\pi }{2}  \right )$. Find the first two times when the
>   velocity is maximum, and the position then.

Here is my working. I then let $x=0$ and did the following:
$$0=6\sin \left (2t+\frac{\pi }{2}  \right )$$ 
$$\pi =2t+\frac{\pi }{2} $$ 
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=2t$$  $$\frac{\pi}{4}=t$$

According to my textbook, the answer I got is incorrect. The provided answer is $t=\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}$.

Could some one please identify where I went wrong and explain the proper way of solving this question?

Comment: You need the velocity to be maximum. You must have gotten a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity is given by $v=12\cos\left(2t+\pi/2\right)$, which is maximised when the cosine of the part in brackets is 1.  This happens when $2t+\pi/2$ is a whole multiple of $2\pi$.  The first two such values of $t$ are $3\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$.

Comment: Could you please explain the maximised part further? I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Cosines vary between -1 and 1.  So if you want them to be maximum, that means they're 1.